# Is it possible to get a PID out of a QLocalSocket connection?

Tags: linux, qt, unix-socket, qlocalsocket, qlocalserver

I'm building a client/server architecture where a client process can connect to a server using local Unix domain sockets.

The server process is implemented in Qt and uses QLocalServer and QLocalSocket to maintain the connection at the server end.

Is there a way to obtain the PID of the connecting client process from the connection information directly? I don't want to trust the client to tell me its PID over the socket connection as there's a risk the client may try to spoof another process's PID.

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: Just GNU/Linux.

Comment: QLocalSocket on *nix uses a file, which obeys POSIX file permissions. Can't you use this for security?

Comment: Not really. I'm relying on the socket being open to client connections by ordinary users, so restricting file permissions isn't relevant here.